# Hosting a private wifi signal from droid

Tags: android, wifi, hotspot

I have been trying to write an app that generates a personal WiFi hotspot from an android device, that funnels webpage and file download requests through the host's mobile data connection. I have managed to request and download the files, but they are being stored under the phone, on the `sdcard\toSendOverWifi\` folder I created.

Quick list of activities done:

1. Recieving device sends webpage/file HTML address request to host
2. Host downloads file over 3g/4g/LTE data connection
3. Host saves file(s) to `sdcard\toSendOverWifi\`
4. (not done) host sends file out to recieving device (only connection)

Ihave not found a class and/or method to send the downloaded files over WiFi to other devices.

What class/method do I need to accomplish this? And is it compatible with non-rooted devices?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use TCP/IP sockets as usual.